# "Make Cyclic F Modifier" is making my animation cycle go out of sync

Tags: animation, modifiers, fcurves

I'm trying to make an infinite cycle of a swimming cycle but and am using an f curves cyclic modifier to make the cycle. The cycle works for the first few minutes but then slowly falls out of sync. How can I fix this?

I'm also working with a lot of bones. Is there a way to just select all of the bone layers in the f curve window and change the cycles modifier settings instead of going layer by layer...

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! Turns out not all of my bone's last keyframes were actually at the last keyframe. For example, my right foot ik's last keyframe was at 125 when it should've been at 130.